# Restore PhpStorm project from the Local History and cache files

Tags: phpstorm

I have an deleted project after format but I still have the cache and Local History files on my system in `.PhpStorm2018.1` folder.

How can I restore the project using these files?

Answer (score 1):

Caches and Local History are bound to a certain `.idea` folder. If you've lost it alongside with other project files, this data is useless.

Also, caches won't do anything in this situation, and Local History is being kept for [5 working days only](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/local-history.html#retention).

Sorry.